# How can I get only the products which have been superseded exactly 3 times?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am having trouble working out how to write a query that will only return me the rows for a product where it has been superseded exactly 3 times.

I have added the V1, V2, V3 bits of text to help explain the problem so I can't just do a "Contains" V3 as that doesn't exist.

Here is my table of data:

```
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| ProductId | SupersededBy | Name         |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| 123456    | 789012       | Car Wheel V1 |
| 789012    | 345678       | Car Wheel V2 |
| 345678    | null         | Car Wheel V3 |
| 901234    | 112233       | Brake Pad V1 |
| 567890    | 778899       | Mirror V1    |
| 112233    | null         | Brake Pad V2 |
| 445566    | null         | Mirror V3    |
| 778899    | 445566       | Mirror V2    |
| 113366    | 224477       | Motor V1     |
| 224477    | 335588       | Motor V2     |
| 335588    | 990011       | Motor V3     |
| 990011    | null         | Motor V4     |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
```

The expected output:

```
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| ProductId | SupersededBy | Name         |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| 345678    | null         | Car Wheel V3 |
| 445566    | null         | Mirror V3    |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: ideally you can also add a version for a "group" that would make the query more easy..  Also which MySQL version are you using as MySQL 8 makes this a bit more easy ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `join`s to follow the chain exactly twice (to get three products):

```
select t.ProductId, t2.ProductId, t3.ProductId
from t t1.join
     t t2
     on t2.SupersededBy = t1.ProductId join
     t t3
     on t3.SupersededBy = t2.ProductId
where t3.SupersededBy is null and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.SupersededBy = t1.ProductId
                 );
```

The `not exists` is to be sure you are starting with the first product.